# How can I get a specific Floor in my Tower?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

I really **really** want a specific floor ([Glass Studio](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Glass_Studio)) in my Tiny Tower.  How does the game decide which exact business will go into the "Creative" floor?  Do I have to meet requirements (such as tower height) to unlock certain floors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The floors are completely random. There is no way to make sure you get a certain floor in a particular category. You just have to wait and hope it shows up when you build.

Comment: What are the consequences of deleting an existing business, and Constructing a new Creative floor in its place?

Comment: You lose that building, obviously, and have to pay (and wait for) a new floor.

Comment: Building a new floor costs coins, but deleting the business or housing on an additional floor costs only the Construction time.  Since I was low on coins, but had time, I just deleted an existing business and built a new Creative floor a few times.  Eventually I got what I needed!

Answer (score 9):

With the recent release of version 2.0 (July 26, 2012 for iOS devices), you can pay Tower Bux to build a specific floor from all of the not-yet-built floors.

You can't do this while a floor is under construction. Once you have built an empty floor (using coins), you tap on the floor and choose "Choose Specific Floor" from below all of the "Random [Floor type]" buttons.

[image: Tiny Tower floor type screenshot showing new floor selection with "Choose Specific Floor" highlighted.]

Comment: You cant choose all business types when choosing a specific floor though