# Chart of how many tower bux each floor costs to buy?

Tags: tiny-tower

In Tiny Tower, I want to soon add a specific floor to my tower. ([You can pick floors since 2.0.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45921)) Doing so costs tower bux depending on what you want to pick, and the screen showing the cost is only available when you have an empty floor ready for construction. I don't currently have an empty floor, and would like to know if I can remotely save up the bux necessary for a shiny new [Bowling Alley](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Bowling_Alley). Is there a listing somewhere of all the costs to pick each [floors](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Floors)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, lacking another resource, I'm going to start building one. Here are the first page (more or less) of shops for each comercial category from my game. In case the listings vary based on the game state, I'm currently playing:

- iOS version, current as of 2012-10-23 (Believed version 2.0.1)
- Tower is 16 floors, including floor ready for construction.
- Tower has 26 residents.

**Food**

- 11 Sushi Bar
- 11 Coffee House
- 13 Mexican Food
- 15 Sub Shop
- 16 Frozen Yogurt
- 16 Smoothie Shop
- 18 Sky Burger
- 18 Diner
- 23 Tea House
- 23 Vegan Food
- (To be continued 26+)

**Service**

- 63 Pharmacy
- 65 Health Club
- 65 Travel Agency
- 75 Day Spa
- 78 Fortune Teller
- 81 Ship & Print
- 98 Bank
- 120 Dentists Office
- 120 Optometrist
- (To be continued 170+)

**Recreation**

- 12 Comedy Club
- 16 Video Rental
- 20 Night Club
- 46 Arcade
- 55 Casino
- 70 Mini Golf
- 90 Rock Climbing
- 91 Aquarium
- 95 Haunted House
- 111 Cineplex
- 111 Bowling Alley
- (To be continued, 115+)

**Retail**

- 17 Toy Store
- 33 Book Store
- 35 Plant Nursery
- 36 Shoe Store
- 43 Bike Shop
- 53 Furniture Store
- 55 Music Store
- 71 Fabric Store
- 73 Game Store
- (To be continued 83+)

**Creative**

- 53 Soda Brewery
- 106 Cake Studio
- 120 Pottery Studio
- 153 Graphic Design
- 160 Glass Studio
- 168 Tattoo Parlor
- 170 TV Studio
- 171 Ad Agency
- 181 Floral Studio
- (To be continued 183+)