# How to get a specific floor in my tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a specific Floor in my Tower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45921/how-can-i-get-a-specific-floor-in-my-tower)

I havent played Tiny Tower in a while, and I was reading that you could select the floor you wanted to build when that floor is under construction. But it didn't mention how you do that; how do I select my floor type while it's under construction?